# Easiest way to modify a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I try to do something like below:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY id int unsigned;
```

and `id` is a primary key or a foreign key, it will throw the following error:

```
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './mydb/#sql-146dd_c' to './mydb/myTable' (errno: 150)
```

If I drop the key doing something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable DROP FOREIGN KEY id;
```

Then I can run my `MODIFY` fine, but this seems a bit convoluted.

Is there any way that I can just `MODIFY` my column without dropping and re-adding my primary keys/foreign keys?

Comment: AFAIK There is no easy way

Comment: I liked the old title. Seemed more descriptive.

Comment: Sorry, no one was looking at it with that one.  It seems like more general titles get more views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed [rename primary keys](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/renaming-columns-and-constraints-9i.php), however, you'll have to temporarily revoke their special status first using [the DROP PRIMARY KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) clause to ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP PRIMARY KEY my_misnamed_primary_key;
ALTER TABLE tbl_name RENAME COLUMN my_misnamed_primary_key TO primary_key;
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD PRIMARY KEY primary_key;
```

Sorry, but for integrity purposes, this is the only way you **should** do so.

Comment: Yeah this is basically what I'm doing in my example, correct?

Comment: Yes, but there is no other way you should be thinking of accomplishing this.

Comment: heh sure, jonesing for some rep?

Comment: Glad you are here to guide me ;)